# How to pass variable from one button click function to another?

Tags: c++-cli

Its kinda dummy question, but how to pass variable from one button click function to another? lets say I have

```
private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
string x;
}

private: System::Void button3_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
passWord(y);
 }
```

and I want to pass variable x to function passWord(y) which launches when I click button3.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well there are many ways to do it. one method is define a class member, such as

```
String ^ x = "some text";
```

then you can use this string in both button event handlers

Comment: well, I need to pass a socket. Is it still available?

Comment: yeah, a socket can be class member. you can use it in both methods.

Comment: ok, gonna define it as a class member, cuz I see there is no other way. Thnak you.